# Using ‘make again’ to clean and remake

Tags: makefile

I want to have a phony target to ‘remake’ a project via `make again` instead of typing `make clean && make` or `make clean all` (which seems like I wanted to ‘clean all’) or making an alias/function/script to do this.

Is it safe to specify something like this:

```
again: clean all
```

in a sense that prerequisites are reliably updated from left to right?
Or, maybe, is it better to do a recursive call like in

```sh
again:
    $(MAKE) clean   # maybe ‘&& \’ here
    $(MAKE) all
```

I mean, may there be any pitfalls or incompatibilities in either approach which could make creating e.g. a shell function or an alias to `make clean && make` safer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it safe to specify something like this:
>
> ```
> again: clean all
> ```
>
> in a sense that prerequisites are reliably updated from left to right?

That's not safe, because `all` does not depend on `clean` so if someone runs `make -j2 again` then the two targets can be run in parallel.

Your second approach will work better, because it ensures that `$(MAKE) all` cannot start before `$(MAKE) clean` has completed. It's not entirely safe though, because if someone does `make -j2 clean again` then *those* two targets could run in parallel, which would be roughly equivalent to `make clean & make clean all`, which would still allow the `all` step to run in parallel with the first `clean`.

A better option would be:

```
again: clean
    $(MAKE) all
```

This way if someone does `make clean again` then it only does the clean once, and if they do `make -j2 clean again` it still ensures that the `clean` target finishes before `$(MAKE) all` runs.

Comment: @user3489199: Note that the parallelism would also be a problem with something like `make -j2 clean all`.

Comment: @DevSolar, yep, but that's harder to avoid. It's pretty easy to make the `again` target handle it correctly.